# Use Sonar in multi module project with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube

My project has this file structure : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html

And I need to apply a sonar scan for all subprojects like this : https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner-for-gradle/#analyzing-multi-project-builds

Here the blocks I have in my build.gradle of the root module :

```
plugins {
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '4.4.1.3373'
}

subprojects {
    sonarqube {
        properties {
            property "sonar.host.url", "myUrl"
            property "sonar.projectKey", "myProjectKey"
            property "sonar.login", "myLogin"
            property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
            property 'sonar.language', 'java'
            property "sonar.qualitygate.wait", true
            property "sonar.sources", "src"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':module1')
    implementation project(':module2')
    implementation project(':module3')
}
```

this root module is under :

```
// myproject root
|
settings.gradle
-- rootmodule
--- build.gradle
-- module1
--- build.gradle
-- module2
--- build.gradle
-- module3
--- build.gradle
```

But in my sonar server only the "rootmodule" is analyzed. Why ?

Comment: your `rootmodule` is not the real root project, so here you only apply sonar plugin to the `rootmodule` subproject, not to other subprojects. your should apply Sonar plugin the the root project directly (in a `build.gradle` file in same level as ``settings.gradle`

Comment: Even if I use other modules in the dependencies block ? It should detect that they are subprojects

Comment: plugins  and  inter-subproject dependencies are two different things,  creating a dependency between subproject A to subproject B will not apply plugins from A to B.

Comment: UPDATE : I removed subprojects block as it's not recommended by Gradle team for best practices and the use for root build.gradle as well. So I still have the same problem. I generated an aggregate jacoco report and ask Sonar to use it in 'rootmodule'. The problem is even if the jacoco report is found, only the rootmodule is analyzed and I think this is the cause : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-gradle?tab=readme-ov-file#how-the-plugin-works So there's a conflict between gradle best practices and sonar plugin recommandations

Comment: "For multi-module projects, the plugin will only apply to the first project where it gets called. The goal is to allow the usage of allprojects {}, for example."

Comment: Ok so I ended up by using this project as tutorial : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/tree/master/sonar-scanner-gradle/gradle-multimodule-coverage